# Presta shop smtp settings are not working with smtp server settings

Tags: php, email, smtp, prestashop

We presta shop 1.5 installed the smtp settings are working with php mailer but not working with prestashop smtp settings.

This is the error i am getting when sending any test email.

"Error: please check your configuration
The SMTP connection failed to start [ssl://smtp.gmail.com:465]: fsockopen returned Error Number 110 and Error String 'Connection timed out'"

I tried using ssl, tls and plain settings but didn't work with them.

Comment: This would be better asked on serverfault.com

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you are configuring correctly smtp has some strict rules you must follow.

```
Mail domain name: pop.yourmail.com
SMTP server: smtp.yourmail.com
SMTP user: johndoe@yourmail.com
SMTP password: your password you use to access your mail
```

check those again...
hope it helps